# Vue js & node js installed. Version also showing but not starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ubuntu

```
kirti@kirti-Vostro-14-3468:~/flipbook-vue$ node --version
v17.6.0
kirti@kirti-Vostro-14-3468:~/flipbook-vue$ vue --version
@vue/cli 5.0.1
kirti@kirti-Vostro-14-3468:~/flipbook-vue$ npm run serve

> flipbook-vue@0.10.4 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
kirti@kirti-Vostro-14-3468:~/flipbook-vue$
```

**System:** Ubuntu 20.04

**Via:** Downloaded via terminal.
I'm running a GitHub repo on my system. I saw the instructions for directly running a github repo on VS Code but as it gave me this error.

I thought, to verify and install vue & node properly first and then run. But, it still gives me error. What can I do?

Comment: Please delete your node module folder and remove your package-lock.json file and then install node modules and then give a try    rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install

Answer (score 1):

restart your system it may help sometime it is important to restart your system after installing nodejs